# Integrate wrapbootstrap theme with Meteorjs

Tags: meteor

We got a wrap bootstrap theme call ace admin. We are trying to integrate the theme into meteorjs.

The structure of the ace admin files folder is:

1. assets

   - avatars
   - css
   - fonts
   - images
   - img
   - js
2. build

   - demo
   - files
   - lib
   - several javascript files here (*.js)
3. dist

   - avatars
   - css
   - fonts
   - images
   - img
   - js

By following the tutorial [here](https://www.yauh.de/using-pre-made-themes-with-meteor/) 
I moved all the static content such as images, fonts, etc to client folder, javascript related folders - (assets, build, dist and all the related content) to public folder.

The problem that I am facing it - Meteor is not loading the javascript files inside the public folder.

Could someone help? Thanks.

**Edit:**
Ok. Finally. Thanks to @Ethaan. After spending almost 2 days figuring out what the problem- its with the javascript loading dependencies. If anyone is facing similar problems - make sure you load all the dependencies first and then load other files.

Do everything in the link provided in the above url that I mentioned and then move all the js folder files to client.

Comment: You should put JS code inside /Lib folder, since lib folder its what meteor loads first, try changing to lib folder

Comment: @Ethaan Actually, the js files has lots of *.html and other image dependencies. So I moved the entire folder containing the *.js, *.html files to lib folder. Meteor is throwing an error related to html files. Should I move "*.js" related folders only?

Comment: since lib folder share code with client, i recommend you to avoid using html on lib

Comment: i didnt see the comment but yes, you should just load JS code on the /Lib folder, tell me if works

Comment: @Ethaan I moved the folder containing the javascript files to lib folder in the root. Meteor is throwing this error in the console "(STDERR) ReferenceError: window is not defined"

Comment: Well this is another little problem since lib folder share code into client/server, server dosnt know about the window object, so you have 2 solutions, making a package with that files, or moving all js inside /client folder, but you should remove it from the /public folder

Comment: @Ethaan Give me few mins. Checking out.

Comment: Di you find the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know some things about meteor structure, You can read [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp)

`/lib` folder its where you put the code you want to share between server/client, code like `Routes,Collectios` or other code ho is available on `server/client`(if you put code which use `"window"` object you will have issues, since windows objects its undefined to the server.)

`/public`folder here is where you put the images, logos, fonts, etc (you get the idea)

`/client` folder here is where you put the code which will be available only to the client

`/server` here is where you put the code only available on the server

I recommend you to read the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp), this was just a quickly explanation.

Comment: Remember the `client/compatibility` folder. Especially when dealing with fragile 3rd party scripts that rely on not being minified or declaring vars this can save you from quite a bit of headache.